# Configure Apache HTTP 2.2 for PUT method

Tags: apache, http, httpd.conf

I've written code for file upload and download using `HttpWebRequest`/`HttpWebResponse` class in C# with Apache 2.2 as a web server. In code I'm using `request.method = "PUT"`.

I want to config my HTTP config file to support `PUT` method. I write PUT method script as:

```
<Location "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/output">
<Dav On
<LimitExcept GET HEAD OPTIONS PUT>
Allow from all
</LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

That's not working. It shows error at program output: *(405) The method not allowed*.

Answer (score 4):

1. Your `<Dav On` directive is not complete (no need for `<`) -- I assume it's just a copy-paste issue.
2. More importantly -- you are using `<Location>` directive ... but providing physical path on your file system/hard drive.

   That's wrong -- **`<Location>` is used to match URLs, not directories**; to match directories you need to use `<Directory>`. Please refer to Apache manual: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#location

   You most likely need to use `<Location /output>` instead (or use `<Directory>` instead of `<Location>`) -- that's my guess based on the amount of config data you have provided.

Taking the above into consideration you will need something like this (sorry, I cannot connect to my Apache box to test it):

```
<Location /output>
    Dav On
    <LimitExcept GET HEAD OPTIONS PUT>
        Allow from all
    </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

Comment: I had some similar issues as the default config listed in the "extra/httpd-dav" file has the <Directory> syntax pre-populated, and I kept receiving 405 errors in the access.log. Since reading this post, I have changed it to <Location> and everything worked like a charm. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Don't you mean Limit rather than LimitExcept? Otherwise you have not allowed any access for PUT.